# Show a message when DOM is not loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

What is the way to show a message as soon a page load starts ... may be it takes 1 minute to load the html etc?

It is a ticket booking website wherein one will start making payment using bank or credit cards. During peak hours the bank sites may load slowly, or fail to load. During this time I want to show a message throughout which customer can click and go back immediately to booking start page if the bank page fails to load or keeps loading for a minute or two.

While making payment customer may have traversed 2-4 pages. Since all pages are using POST .. using Back button gives cache-miss etc error. However booking start page can be reaching by a GET url.

Comment: Considering that ways to do that are certainly different in Firefox and Chrome, I highly suggest making 2 separate questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "load starts" and "show a message"? Both can be interpreted in a variety of ways.

Comment: @RobW I've update it

Comment: @user5858 That functionality is called the Back button (and browser's error page), and all browsers already support it (arrow left). What is your role in this (i.e. over which parts of the system do you have control)? Detecting load failure is easy via the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events, but maybe there is a better way to really meet your needs.

Comment: @RobW I've added the explanation. Back button gives cache-miss as those are all POST based.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can show a notification bar, and as it loads you can remove it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications#Using_notification_box

The notification bar can be visible in all tabs, or just a specific tab, this code makes the bar be visible in that tab only:

```
var message = 'Another pop-up blocked';
var box = gBrowser.getNotificationBox();
var notification = box.getNotificationWithValue('popup-blocked');
if (notification) {
    notification.label = message;
}
else {
    var buttons = [{
        label: 'Button',
        accessKey: 'B',
        popup: 'blockedPopupOptions',
        callback: null
    }];

    let priority = box.PRIORITY_WARNING_MEDIUM;
    box.appendNotification(message, 'popup-blocked',
                           'chrome://browser/skin/Info.png',
                            priority, buttons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This outline should work:

1. page 1 posts a request for page 2
2. page 2 returns a simple 'loading' page, and makes an inline AJAX request of the form, while the rest of the page loads.
3. the callback from the AJAX populates the page as expected (replacing a high-level container), OR you can offer advice if too much time passes by.